# Spring Boot 2.0 with OAuth 2.0, performance in IDE different with jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0

I build an OAuth2 Server,with jwt token. I try to login with password mode,and when  I run my code in IDEA, all goes well,but when I package it to jar,I cant login and get Exception. here's my debug log in IDE and jar.

[IN IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJxOw.png)

[IN JAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiHXV.jpg)

I debug into deep and find that when it run in ProviderManager, the provider is different between IDE and jar.
In IDE,I can see mongoDao written by myself,but in jar,there's an exception.

[IN IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQPoU.png)

[IN JAR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAh5d.png)

can any one tell me whats happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out, it's because I declared a ClientDetailsService myself, and there's another ClientDetailsService with the same name by default;when I run the code with IDE, the new Bean is used,when I run the code in jar,the default Bean is used,so I added the @Primary annotation to set my Bean to be used.But I still don't know why it's different between IDE and jar.